# EF Core - Pattern to save with a reference navigation property (foreign key)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Let's say I want to add `Instruments` in my database with many reference navigation properties such as a `Currency`.

When I want to add an instrument I will find the currency through a method `GetCurrencyFromName` in another class which has its own datacontext.

That means I have to attach every navigation property before saving the new `Instrument`. Is it alright to proceed this way or is it smarter to pass the datacontext to the `GetCurrencyFromName`.

Is there a specific pattern for that ?

For my example:

```
    public class Bond : Instrument
    {
        public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    }

    public class Currency
    {
        public int CurrencyId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide us some sample classes?

Comment: ok I have added a minimal example